# How to get list of file names in downloads folder?

Tags: android

I tried this:

```
File f =Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

        System.out.println(f.list());
        System.out.println(f.listFiles().toString());
```

But it shows null.
I have given permissions for read and write in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is **dangerous** permission You need to ask it runtime permission

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

You need to [ask runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

and also try this

Try this

```
private void getfiles() {
    String[] filenames = new String[0];
    ArrayList<String> fileArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder_name");
    if (path.exists()) {
        filenames = path.list();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
        fileArrayList.add(path.getPath() + "/" + filenames[i]);
        Log.e("fileArrayList", fileArrayList.get(i));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks asking for the runtime permissions  solved my problem.

Comment: @user6731698 happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

```
File f = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

List<String> files = getList(f);


private List<String> getList(File parentDir, String pathToParentDir) {
ArrayList<String> inFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] fileNames = parentDir.list();

for (String fileName : fileNames) {
    if (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt") || 
fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".rtf") || 
fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".doc") || 
fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txd")) {
        inFiles.add(pathToParentDir + fileName);
    } else {
        File file = new File(parentDir.getPath() + "/" + fileName);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            inFiles.addAll(getList(file, pathToParentDir + fileName + "/"));
        }
    }
}

return inFiles;
}
```